# List devices in LAN Linux

Tags: linux, networking, bash, home-networking, raspberry-pi

So I'm trying to find the MAC and IP addresses of all devices connected to LAN on my RaspberryPi running Raspbian. So far I've tried to get the list with:

```
$ arp
$ sudo arp-scan -l
$ sudo nmap -sn 10.0.0.1/24
```

...but they're not really reliable. If for e.g. my phone connects to the network sometimes it'll be found immediately and sometimes not. I would like to find a way to discover all newly connected devices quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Arp will list your arp-cache. This is the list of devices that your system has had contact with.

The nmap scan will contact all the devices, so after the nmap scan, `arp` will list all the devices. So, if you do it in the sequence

```
$ nmap 10.0.0.0/24 > /dev/null
$ arp
```

you should get the complete list.